# If colums of an $n\times n$ matrice are linearly independent then columns of transpose of this matrice are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is a very short:

''If colums of an $n\times n$ matrice are linearly independent then columns of transpose of this matrice are linearly independent''

Is this true? Can you explain? Thanks...

Comment: This is a very famous and very fundamental result with generalizations in many directions. Here is a modest generalization to $m \times n$ rectangular matrices and matrices in which not necessarily ALL columns are linearly independent: *row rank equals column rank*

Answer (score 1):

If the columns of $M$ are linearly independant, then they form a basis of your space. In particular, $M$ is invertible. Hence the transpose of $M$ is also invertible, and therefore, its columns are also linearly independant.